# Can you have different compilers and resolvers on Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a Stack project that can build both GHCJS and GHC binaries. How can I specify on `stack.yaml` that builds should use both compilers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to either

- use two different files, say `ghc.yaml` and `ghcjs.yaml`, you can then use `stack --stack-yaml ghc.yaml` or `stack --stack-yaml ghcjs.yaml` to use those

  - you can set the compiler `ghc` or `ghcjs` by setting the `resolver` (see [haskellstack.org/config#resolver](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html#resolver))
  - or there is a compiler option (see [haskellstack.org/config#compiler](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html#compiler))
- or directly use the commandline option `--compiler`